# Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in c:\wamp\www\drupal2\includes\common.inc on line 551

Tags: php, drupal, configuration, ini

when I go to admin option in drupal 6. I get following error on my Browser

> Fatal Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   c:\wamp\www\drupal2\includes\common.inc on line 551

This error has started occuring after i install 'Views' module in my drupal 6 sites/all/modules folder.

why this is happening? Please Help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Using *wamp* its ***pretty simple*** thing , Click on the wamp icon on taskbar, go to php and go to php.ini and then find `max_execution_time` and make `30 to 500` or more what u are comfort with.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

in the wamp menu (click open the php.ini file and search for

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

and change 30 to 180 or more,
than restart your  apache

Answer (score 1):

Something about the 'Views' module is taking longer than 30 secs to process (Line 551). You can try to increase the maximum execution time by adding the following to your php script:

```
set_time_limit(int $seconds);
```

By default php is set to 30 seconds. Using the above command you can increase it incrementally to see if it will run. If you continue to get the same error I would suggest Isolating and fixing the script or uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in settings.php and then it will work without error

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```