# Maximum execution time of 30 second exceeded in c:\wamp\drupal\includes\database.mysqli.inc on line 114

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

When i extract .ZIP files(Modules e.g Ubercart,cck) on sites/all/modules Folder in drupal 6 and try to enable it from admin->modules and when i click 'save configuration.' i got the errors  As shown in image.

why this happens ??
Is it require to edit database.mysqli.inc

How to correct  it.. Please help.

thank you.!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CogE7.png)

Comment: You asked nearly exactly the same question an hour ago (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793217/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-c-wamp-www-drupal). The responses to the question are correct, please do not post duplicate questions.

Answer (score 3):

The error you're receiving is because the PHP script was executing more than it's allowed by your settings. Try setting `max_execution_time=180` or higher in php.ini and restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the time limit for your scripts (e.g. using [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)), try to process chunks of data instead of one big file at once (and check up front) or try to optimize the code so it takes not so long to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I simply edited sites/default/settings.php and added the following line:

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

by:

Keith Adler

https://drupal.org/node/66105

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the parameters for `max_execution_time=30` and setting it for a greater value. That did not work. But when I tried `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` at the top of my file, it worked and the problem was solved.

Comment: Your first change (to `php.ini`) would not have taken effect until you restarted Apache. I'm guessing you either forgot to restart, or you made an error when changing the configuration file.